# Cant redirect my main domain to herokuapp domain using CNAME

Tags: cname

I want to redirect my existing domain to heroku app, so I create a heroku app for this, when I tried to change `CNAME(Alias)` to `mydomain.herokuapp.com` just after save, I saw that one trailing `DOT` sign put after my heroku link and it looks like this: `mydomain.herokuapp.com.`
So when I enter my main domain to browser I get: *"No such app found"* message, because it redirects to `mydomain.herokuapp.com.` address.

Means I can't delete `.` (trailing dot), my domain registerer is enom and I purchased domain via Google marketplace.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.enom.com/help/configHelp.htm

If you don't have a trailing dot, the DNS will automatically append your domain name.

So if you own `example.com` and you CNAME `www` to `mydomain.heroku.com`, it will try to send you to `mydomain.heroku.com.example.com`.

But if you CNAME it to `mydomain.heroku.com.`, it will actually point to `mydomain.heroku.com` which is what you wanted.